# How to set website URL in GA4 data stream using Google Analytics Admin API?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to create GA4 data stream using Google Analytics Admin API.
Although the creation itself is completed without any error, website URL is not set.
I don't know how to set it.
I'm using GAS.

I tryed to refer the documents of Google Analtics Admin API below.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1beta/properties.dataStreams?hl=ja#DataStream
However, I couldn't find any corresponding field.

Comment: It is part of [WebStreamData](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1beta/properties.dataStreams?hl=ja#WebStreamData) .. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: The part of WebStreamData is Stream URL not Website URL.